# Intellij Disable Parameter hint during typing

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Can't figure out how to disable the pop up parameter hint during typing. I've tried to disable parameter hint in settings for "Show parameter name hints" but I don't believe that effects the below. It's annoying because it keeps getting in the way of my typing.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure the behavior of the view "Parameter information" functionality, go to:

`Preferences > Editor > General > Code Completion`

In the "Parameter Info" section you can increase the time or disable `Autopopup in (ms)...`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the **popup**, You could use **ESC** key to hide the popup when the **parameter info popup** display.